# How to update appsettings.json with variables using Azure DevOps for .NET Core App?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps I'm deploying an App Service (.NET Core app) and would like to update the appsettings.json file with the correct variables. How do I do this?

I first thought of updating the "Application and Configuration Settings", which updated the App Service with "Application Settings", however the appsettings.json is not updateed at all. What am I doing wrong?

Example of "App Settings": -ClientId $(ClientId) -ClientSecret ($ClientSecret)

Comment: Use another file to override the settings instead. That's how `appsettings.Production.js` and `appsettings.Staging.js` work. There's nothing special about the files. The .NET Core configuration system loads settings from multiple sources and when a key is encountered multiple times, the last setting wins. By default, `appsettings.json` is loaded first, followed by the environment specific files, environment variables and finally CLI parameters. Y

Comment: ou could create an `appsettings.Staging.json` just for your staging environment or specify the new settings through [Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables-1)

Comment: How can I override the appsettings using the variable groups? I want to prevent having the appsettings.json filled in the Repository with credentials used in dbConnectionString or ClientSecret.

Comment: You need to use token replacer. Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61736613/2347999).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable substitution in config, JSON files in Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734755/variable-substitution-in-config-json-files-in-azure-devops-pipeline)